# Accessing the Command and CommandParameter properties of buttons within a user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have a simple user control that I'm building (something akin to the illustrations below) which is essentially a user control containing a number of buttons.

[image]

The main control itself does not have a command or command parameter property, but the four buttons inside it do and I wish to be able to access those from the view model of whatever views I happen to place this control on.

Put simply what is the best way to do this.  I simply want to know which button was clicked.  Each button is named (so that would I presume take care of the identification side).

Thanks for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to get a method called within your viewmodel when one of those 4 buttons is clicked.

A simplified view on the general relationship between viewmodel and view could help. From a view perspective the viewmodel is typically accessed via the datacontext property, i.e. the datacontext propery contains the viewmodel object.

Therefore, set the datacontext in xaml or code behind of your main user control to the viewmodel object that you want to use and bind from the buttons command propeties to the appropriate ICommand properties on the viewmodel that you set before.

```
namespace UserControlTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MainUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Command = new RelayCommand((obj) => Debug.Print("done"));
        }

        private ICommand _command;
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return _command;
            }
            set
            {
                _command = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Command");
            }
        }


        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _execute = execute; _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="UserControlTest.MainUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="50" Command="{Binding Command}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I understand the concepts of DataContext and relay commands.  My problem at present is accessing the Buttons' command properties which aren't directly exposed by the user control.  So for example should I be creating a command and command parameter property on the user control itself and hooking the buttons up to that, which in turn I could then connect to via my view model and relay commands?

Comment: Via the datacontext, it is possible to bind directly from the button to the viewmodel withoud creating a command property on the user control itself. You can see that in the xaml example at the end of the code I provided. This is possible because the datacontext value is inherited along the logical tree (set it for the user control, use it on the button). I would prefer this approach because creating commands on the user control feels to me like duplicating the commands on the buttons. I think I cannot help any further without more detailed information about your example.

Comment: Thank you, that's taught me something I hadn't realised that you could do. Now one quick question.  In your example xaml on the user control for the button, if I wanted to pass that button as the commandParameter how should I phrase it in the xaml?

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}". But it is not a good practice to use a button object in the view model, because it mixes view and viewmodel objects. Anyway, have a nice evening.